# Which command to use for getting Bytes per cluster and Bytes per File record segment data for multiple servers?

Tags: windows, powershell, disk, powershell-remoting

I would like to generate Bytes per cluster and Bytes per File record segment data for over 50 servers into an excel sheet (for a drive D)

I know the command "Fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo [drive letter:]" provides this info but only for local system.

i tried writing this but it did not work.

"Enter-PSSession Server1

Fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo D:

Exit-PSSession"

I then executed each command manually and it was working.

Can anyone please help me create a script to get the above mentioned data at one go for 50 servers.

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) where you can feed it a list of server names and have them run your `Fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo D:` command in a scriptblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, you can use cmdlet Invoke-Comand for that:

```
# you may already have admin permissions on each of the servers, but if not, get craedentials for someone that has
$adminCreds = Get-Credential -Message 'Please add your admin credentials to get server information'

# your list of server names here
$servers    = 'Server01', 'Server02'  # etc. 

# next use 'Invoke-Command' to have each server run the code
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -Credential $adminCreds -ScriptBlock {
    # have each server run the Fsutil command, and return that as PsCustomObject for convenience
    # instead of an array of lines. 
    # to use ConvertFrom-StringData in PowerShell < 7.x, you need to replace the first colon with a equals sign
    # PowerShell versions above 5.1 can use parameter  -Delimiter '='
    [PsCustomObject]((Fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo D:) -replace '(?<!:.*):', '=' -join "`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData)
}
```

Now you can save the entire result to CSV or limit to the properties you need like

```
$result | Select-Object PSComputerName, 'Bytes Per Cluster', 'Bytes Per FileRecord Segment' | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\serverInfo.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

If you are not sure all of the servers can be reached, do a loop:

```
$result = foreach ($server in $servers) {
    # test if the server can be reached
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $adminCreds -ScriptBlock {
            # have each server run the Fsutil command, and return that as PsCustomObject for convenience
            # instead of an array of lines. 
            # to use ConvertFrom-StringData in PowerShell < 7.x, you need to replace the first colon with a equals sign
            # PowerShell versions above 5.1 can use parameter  -Delimiter '='
            [PsCustomObject]((Fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo D:) -replace '(?<!:.*):', '=' -join "`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData)
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Server $server is off-line!"
    }
}
```

Regex details:

```
(?<!        Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind)
   :        Match the character “:” literally
   .        Match any single character
      *     Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)          
:           Match the character “:” literally
```

Comment: i will check it out, thanks a lot